# how to force an event to wait for resolving a promise in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, events, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I have an angular-ui-router event '$stateChangeStart':

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  self.onUrlChange_(event);
});
```

and my onUrlChange_ function, like:

```
function onUrlChange_(event) {
  ModalDialog.show('confirm', { //this is promise
    bodyContent: {
      i18n: 'forms.unsavedConfirmMessage'
    }
  }).then(function() {}, function () {
    event.preventDefault();
  })
}
```

So, I want prevent event only if promise was rejected. But this code does not work because of event continues to execute and does not wait for the promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slight variation to your code. This approach basically cancels the event first and then does a prompt. If prompt is successfull state change event is manually triggered again.

A separate Boolean variable keeps track of if you have already prompted user and prevents you from getting stuck into a loop. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
//Have an outer variable to check if user has already been shown the modal prompt
var isWarned=false;
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (isWarned === false) {
        //Cancel the original event
        event.preventDefault();
        ModalDialog.show('confirm', {
            bodyContent: {
                i18n: 'forms.unsavedConfirmMessage'
            }
        }).then(function() {}, function() {
            //Mark the isWarned flag so user is not warned again.Resume the navigation
            isWarned = true;
            $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
        })
    }
});
```